# Extract numbers pattern of a String and put into a Object

Tags: java, regex, string, templates

I have an array with multiples Integer codes of differents sizes, I would parse these numbers to an objects. The lenghts of the codes are always the same.

For example, a pattern would be this:

"123454212323"

- 2 first digits in 1 attribute of object (12)
- 3 next digits in another attribute (345)
- 1 next digit in another attribute (4)
- last 6 digits in another attribute (212323)

I tried with regex but I think it's too complex... There are any elegant / easer way to do this? I need this for 10 diferents patterns and I would know the best solution.

I can use external libraries like Dozer.

Comment: Have you tried substring?

Comment: Can the length of a coded value uniquely identify which parsing rules to use?  Is the resulting object always of the same type, just with different populated attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly `String#substring()` is probably the best way to go here.  If you really wanted a regex based solution, here is one way:

```
String input = "123454212323";
input = input.replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d)(\\d{6})", "$1 $2 $3 $4");
String[] attributes = input.split(" ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(attributes));
```

This prints:

```
[12, 345, 4, 212323]
```

The strategy here is to take your numeric string input and then do a regex replacement to separate the various number groups by space.  Then, we can do a simple string split to obtain an array with each attribute as a separate element.

```
123454212323 -> 12 345 4 212323
```

Comment: Also note that regex is usually slow, so if performance is a concern, substring is the way to go.

Comment: I didn't want to use substring because I have a String with 15 codes, and I was finding something like replaceAll method. But If you think the best option is substring, I'll create a generic function to parse multiples codes.